# Prove that a set of vectors which contains the zero vector is linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Solution I found as :
Let $u,v,w$ be vectors and $a,b,c$ as scalars now linear combination is:
$a.u + b.v + c.w =0$ has the solution $a=1 , b=0, c=0$ which is not all zeroes and thus s is linearly dependent.

HOW $a=1 , b=0 , c=0$ is solution, WHY can't $a=0$?

Comment: A CAN be 0. But that is the trivial solution to a homgenous system (it is always a solution) What tells us whether a system is LD or LI is whether this homogenous equation is determinated or indeterminated. Since the solution is not unique, it is an indeterminated system, and thus an LD set

Comment: Another way to see this is that a set is LI if none of its vectors can be expressed as a linear combination of the other two. But a = 0b * 0c which is a linear combination of b and c. So your set is LI

Answer (score 6):

If $a=0$ then all $a=b=c=0$, and it does not contradict linear independence. But if $a=1$ and $b=c=0$ then it is not all $a,b,c$ that are zeros ($a\ne 0$). At the same time, if $u$ is the zero vector then
$$
a\cdot \vec u+b\cdot \vec v+c\cdot\vec w= 1\cdot\vec 0+0\cdot\vec v+0\cdot \vec w=\vec 0,
$$
thus it is possible to get a zero linear combination by a nonzero coefficients, hence linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Put the coefficient of zero vector a non-negative scalar and other coefficients zero scalar.